# Hard permutations and combinations problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The question says

> A minibus has 11 passenger seats. There are six seats in a row on the sunny side and five seats in a row on the shady side, as shown in the following diagram.
>
> [image]
>
> Find how many ways eight passengers can be arranged in these seats if:
>
> a) there are no restrictions
>
> b) one particular passenger refuses to sit on the sunny side
>
> c) two particular passengers refuse to sit in seats that are either 
>      next to each other or one directly in front of the other.

Here is what I did for (a) and (b):

a) $11P8=6652800$

b) $5C1\times 10P7=3024000$

I am now stuck on (c). The answer is given as $4959360$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $11P8-2*(4+5+5)*9P6=4959360.$ Can you see why?

Comment: So we basically exclude all the `font-back` and `next` to cases... Yes, I see that now. I was over-thinking a bit.

Comment: Is this calculation actually correct? or Am I missing something?

Comment: @CasperYC yes that is correct.

Comment: You missed a facotor of `P2P=2` for the second term ...

Comment: But yes, the idea is correct.

Comment: Yes it's fixed now.